# netty: get OutputStream for writing

Tags: sockets, netty, outputstream

Im starting with netty and need some help.

I dont understand, how can i get the OutputStream of the channel to write in.
I have already an UpstreamHandler (decoder), that reads a Request and decodes it - now i would like to write back (an answer for the connected client).
I can write a String (from examples from netty site), but i would like to write directly to some OutputStream (my busines logic method has an OutpuStream as parameter, to which data is written).

How can i do it with netty?

Comment: If you want an output stream why are you using Netty at all? Why not just `java.net?`

Comment: because its very simple with netty to start a socket server - for other projects, where i had string decoded->busines logic->string encoded communication, netty is perfect

Answer (score 3):

In Netty you use "Channel.write(..)" to write data back to the client. If you really need to write to an OutputStream you could do it with:

```
ChannelBufferOutputStream out = new ChannelBufferOutputStream(ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer());
yourObject.handle(out);
Channel.write(out.buffer());
```

An other approach would be to write an OutputStream that wraps an Channel.